# Not able to request token

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, guzzle

To use Microsoft Graph, I'm trying to authenticate on behalf of the user. I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) tutorial, and I'm currently stuck at step 3.

When requesting the token, I receive a `400 Bad Request` response:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_scope",
  "error_description": "AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter."
}
```

Even though I'm including a scope parameter, this is my request:

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => [
    'Host' => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ]
]);

$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token';
$token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => '################################',
        'scope' => 'user.read%20mail.read',
        'code' => $_GET['code'],
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://eb3ef49e.ngrok.io/callback.php',
        'client_secret' => '################'
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is tagged as ms-access and outlook.  What does this question or the code have to do with either of those?  Please choose the minimal set of tags that have to do with the immediate question, not all aspects of the overall project.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the complete error description says:

> `AADSTS70011`: The provided request must include a '`scope`' input
>   parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not
>   valid. The scope `user.read%20mail.read` is not valid. The scope
>   format is invalid. Scope must be in a valid URI form
>   `<https://example/scope>` or a valid Guid `<guid/scope>`.

If so, then Azure AD endpoint could not recognize the provided `scope` here. `/token` endpoint expects `scope` parameter to be specified as *a space-separated list of scopes*   . Meaning there is no need to *explicitly* escape space symbol here:

```
'scope' => 'user.read%20mail.read'
```

instead specify it like this:

```
'scope' => 'user.read mail.read'
```

and and [Guzzle client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) will do the rest of constructing the encoded body for `/token` endpoint